# Java Client Libraries: Configure read timeouts?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am using the official Java client libraries (https://github.com/Asana/java-asana/) and I am frequently running into

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

and

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

problems. Is there any chance to configure those values, e.g. like done via

```
URLConnection.setReadTimeout
```

?

Answer (score 0):

For the meantime, this solution can be used. This however, includes copying code from the Asana client libraries, which is problematic. I've created an issue: https://github.com/Asana/java-asana/issues/47

```
new Client(new AccessTokenDispatcher(personalAccessToken) {
    @Override
    public HttpRequest buildRequest(String method, GenericUrl url, HttpContent content) throws IOException {
        HttpRequest request = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(req -> {
            req.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
            req.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        }).buildRequest(method, url, content);
        request.getHeaders().setAuthorization("Bearer " + personalAccessToken);
        return request;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter! We'll take a look at the issue and figure out how we might add a configuration setting to do this without copying out the original code.